# Monitoring and storing chat logs in a 3D space

Tags: community-management

There are a lot of 3D games on the market with text chat functionality holding literally thousands of conversations happening at the same time.

Being in a 3D space is there a defacto method of monitoring and storing these?

The difficulty I can see is that not all text is visible to all participants at all times meaning a raw chat log wouldn't make any sense, with having so many conversations occurring in real time.

Comment: Err, what's wrong with simply logging the 3d coordinates if they're relevant?

Comment: Just log everything in chronological order along with coordinates, and have your log reader be able to filter by location.

Answer (score 1):

> The difficulty I can see is that not all text is visible to all
>   participants at all times meaning a raw chat log wouldn't make any
>   sense, with having so many conversations occurring in real time.

True location-based chat, chat that only appears to users within a particular radius of some coordinate in 3D space is relatively uncommon.

Games typically have chats that are global (everybody can see them), map- or team-based, as well as private user-to-user conversations. None of these are constrained by physical location and anything that monitors or stores them just needs to know *which* map or team the entire chat stream is associated with. Similarly, user-to-user chats just need to log which participants are involved. Percentage-wise, you get more of that kind of chat than you do the true location-based stuff.

True location-scoped chat can simply store the world location with each message, if needed. It's not a lot of extra data, and there are ways one could in theory optimize the storage if it really became an issue.

Monitoring and logging that chat is then simply a matter of including an optional location query in whatever monitoring tools exist. There's no need for anything complicated.

In fact, chat forensics are usually more concerns with *what was said*, rather than *who heard it*, so in general being able to execute a query like "show me all the chat said between 9am and 11pm that could be heard at this location" is not a tool one reaches for all that often.